# RavenDB Linq query ignores "Where" and "OrderBy" statements after "Select"

Tags: ravendb

I have a list of documents in my RavenDB instance. Those documents have a list of nested objects that contain a number value in a string format. I need to find the document that has the highest value in a specific nested object of this list. I have no control over the document layout.

Here's the query that I'm using, and a simplified version of the test data:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Raven.Client.Documents;
using Raven.Client.Documents.Session;
using Raven.Embedded;

namespace RavenTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EmbeddedServer.Instance.StartServer();
            using (var store = EmbeddedServer.Instance.GetDocumentStore("Embedded"))
            {
                GenerateTestData(store);
                QueryForEmployeeWithHighestGenericDataValue(store);
            }
        }

        private static void QueryForEmployeeWithHighestGenericDataValue(IDocumentStore store)
        {
            using (var session = store.OpenSession())
            {
                var query = session.Query<Employee>()
                    .Where(x => x.NestedGenericData != null)
                    .Where(x => x.NestedGenericData.Any(y => y.Key == "SomeKeyToFind"))
                    .Select(x =>
                        new
                        {
                            Value = x.NestedGenericData.First(y => y.Key == "SomeKeyToFind").Value,
                            Employee = x.FirstName
                        })
                    .Where(x => x.Value != null)
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Value, OrderingType.AlphaNumeric);

                var employeeWithHighestValue = query.FirstOrDefault();

                if (employeeWithHighestValue.Value != "42")
                {
                    var allObjectsOrderedWithoutNulls = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                        query.ToList(),
                        new JsonSerializerSettings { Formatting = Formatting.Indented });

                    throw new Exception($"Should be 42, but is {employeeWithHighestValue.Value}");
                }
            }
        }

        private static void GenerateTestData(IDocumentStore store)
        {
            using (var session = store.OpenSession())
            {
                // generate Id automatically
                session.Store(new Employee
                {
                    FirstName = "John10",
                    NestedGenericData = new List<GenericData>
                        {
                            new GenericData
                            {
                                Key = "SomeKeyToFind",
                                Value = "10"
                            },
                        }
                });
                session.Store(new Employee
                {
                    FirstName = "JohnNull",
                    NestedGenericData = new List<GenericData>
                        {
                            new GenericData
                            {
                                Key = "SomeKeyToFind",
                                Value = null
                            },
                        }
                });
                session.Store(new Employee
                {
                    FirstName = "John3",
                    NestedGenericData = new List<GenericData>
                        {
                            new GenericData
                            {
                                Key = "SomeKeyToFind",
                                Value = "3"
                            },
                        }
                });
                session.Store(new Employee
                {
                    FirstName = "John42",
                    NestedGenericData = new List<GenericData>
                        {
                            new GenericData
                            {
                                Key = "SomeKeyToFind",
                                Value = "42"
                            },
                        }
                });
                session.Store(new Employee
                {
                    FirstName = "JohnNoGenericData",
                    NestedGenericData = new List<GenericData>
                        {
                            new GenericData
                            {
                                Key = "SomeOtherKey",
                                Value = "123"
                            },
                        }
                });
                session.Store(new Employee
                {
                    FirstName = "John1",
                    NestedGenericData = new List<GenericData>
                        {
                            new GenericData
                            {
                                Key = "SomeKeyToFind",
                                Value = "1"
                            },
                            new GenericData
                            {
                                Key = "SomeOtherKey",
                                Value = "123"
                            },
                        }
                });

                // send all pending operations to server, in this case only `Put` operation
                session.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    internal class GenericData
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Employee
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public List<GenericData> NestedGenericData { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This code, if pasted into a new .NET core console app with `Install-Package RavenDB.Embedded -Version 4.1.0` installed and executed, will return `employeeWithHighestValue` whose `Value` field equals to `"10"` and the `Employee` field equals to `"John10"`.

The value of the `allObjectsOrderedWithoutNulls` (i.e. the dump of the whole query) will contain this:

```
[
  {
    "Value": "10",
    "Employee": "John10"
  },
  {
    "Value": null,
    "Employee": "JohnNull"
  },
  {
    "Value": "3",
    "Employee": "John3"
  },
  {
    "Value": "42",
    "Employee": "John42"
  },
  {
    "Value": "1",
    "Employee": "John1"
  }
]
```

This neither has the projection entries with `x.Value == null` filtered off, nor is it ordered descendingly by the `Value` field (AlphaNumerically, or otherwise).

**The question:**

What is wrong with my query?

Why do the LINQ statements after the `Select` seem to not apply?

What is the correct way to get the data that I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using '`.Select`' in your query which is a '**Projection**'.

Projections can only be applied as the **last** stage in the query pipeline - after documents have been processed, filtered, sorted and paged.
So you can't apply `Where` after `Select`.

See: [Projecting Individual Fields](https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/queries/projecting-individual-fields)

See: [Query Example](https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/queries/query-example)

Comment: So the LINQ query that I've defined in a certain order and expect to be executed in a certain order (as every LINQ statement ever) cannot be executed in that order, and, instead of failing with an Exception, it just silently executes out of order? 

Okay then, that makes sense. Can you suggest how the Query can be reorganized to return the results that I expect? Maybe adding a new index with the projection is required?